# distinguishing forward and backward quote in lstlisting

Tags: fonts, listings

I'm using the listings package to render source code in a latex document.   Unfortunately, it is very difficult to distinguish forward and backquote in the rendered document.   What is the suggested way of resolving this?

In the programming language which I'm writing about, the distinction between these two characters is important, and I don't want the reader to have to guess which one is being used.

Here is some sample code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  language=Lisp,
  emph={},
  keywords={}
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  `(something which uses backquote)
  '(something using normal quote)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could try the `minted` package instead of `listings`, that might be more clear for this type of characters.

Comment: I find a clear distinction between the symbols; the issue is that the backquote is a left quote not a backtick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `upquote` option is used to display code-style quotes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\lstset{%
  language=Lisp,
  emph={},
  keywords={}
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  upquote=true
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  `(something which uses backquote)
  '(something using normal quote)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> upquote=<true|false> (default false)
>
> determines whether the left and right quote are printed ‘’ or `'. This key
>   requires the textcomp package if true.

All I've done is add the option and `\usepackage{textcomp}`